# TimePickerDialog cancel button

Tags: android

I have an activity - TimePickerActivity - which creates a TimePickerDialog.  I have a onTimeSetListener which responds to the Set button at the end of which it calls finish() and returns to the activity that called the TimePickerActivity.   I want it to finish and return if the Cancel button is clicked but can't find any way to do this.   I have googled and tried out severall suggestions but none of them seem to work.  Any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just pass an [onCancelListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/DialogInterface.OnCancelListener.html) to [TimePicker.setOnCancelListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener))

**edit:** After Ron's problems with implementation I decided to actually test myself the code (I answered just looking at the API) and I discovered than even if the code is correct (I suppose you had a typo somewhere as my code compiles ok), when clicking the cancel button it didn't respond as intended...

It appears that when you click `cancel` button the Dialog doesn't call the `cancel()` method that fires the `OnCancelListener` as it would seem the obvious, but the `dismiss()` method that fires an `OnDismissListener`, pretty weird...

So this code is working fine for me:

```
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        //time set stuff
    }
};
TimePickerDialog myTPDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener,0,0,false);
myTPDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Cancel code here
    }
});
myTPDialog.show();
```

all credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125879/how-to-make-a-listener-for-a-datepickers-cancel-button-in-android) SO answer...

Comment: TimePickerDialog myTPDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener,0,0,false);
 
 OnCancelListener ocl = new OnCancelListener() {
  public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
  
  }
  };
 
 TimePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener( ocl);

Comment: error with :- Syntax error on token "ocl", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token  and Syntax error on token(s), misplaced constructs

Comment: I need to amend the above but cant find an edit facility and is there a better way to enter code and why does this comment close when a type a cr.   Sorry if this seems obvious but not to me.

Comment: replace `TimePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(ocl);` with `myTPDialog.setOnCancelListener(ocl);`

Comment: maid: that produces 
Syntax error on token "ocl", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token 
Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: maid:  that did it - many thanks.  I looked again in the android developer reference and the section dealing with onDismiss and OnCancel don't seem to tally with this succesful solution!

Comment: Doesn't the onDismiss listener also get triggered when the ok button is clicked?

Comment: After seeing binW's answer, I was able to finally write a running solution. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724781/timepickerdialog-cancel-button/47043247#47043247

Answer (score 4):

here is how I did it:

```
TimePickerDialog tp = new TimePickerDialog(this, mTimeSetListener, 0, 0, false);
tp.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        {
            tbTimer.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, but when clicked outside a dialog, a click event is not catched.

Comment: Thanks binW! You showed me the path and I reached the destination. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724781/timepickerdialog-cancel-button/47043247#47043247

Answer (score 2):

```java
TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
            //ok button clicked 
    }
};

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int now_hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int now_minutes = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

final TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, now_hour, now_minutes + 1, false);

timePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        //cancel button clicked
    }
});

timePickerDialog.show();
```

Comment: If you timePickerDialog.setCancelable(false), then the user must explicitly press ok or cancel, which prevents cancelling on dismiss.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is based on @maid450 answer, remark of @Fortega and a fact that OnDismissListener is called (usually in last turn) on any click when a time picker dialog is shown.

```
private int timeSetStatus; // A clicked button result.

...

timeSetStatus = 0;
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
final TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        timeSetStatus = 1;
        // Other actions.
    }
}, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), 0, true);
dialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        timeSetStatus = 2;
        // Actions on clicks outside the dialog.
    }
});
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if (timeSetStatus == 0) {
            // Actions on Cancel button click.
        }
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just override (kotlin sample code)

```
override fun onCancel(dialog: DialogInterface?) {
   super.onCancel(dialog)
   callback?.onCancelClick()
}
```

method inside my DialogFragment and called onCancelClick of my interface:

```
interface SetAlarmTimeListener: TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    fun onCancelClick()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally a running solution...

Declare a boolean variable in class as below:

```
private boolean isTimeSelected;
```

Then on button click call the following method:

```
public void onButtonClicked() {
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP || isTimeSelected) {
                lastSelectedHour = selectedHour;
                lastSelectedMinute = selectedMinute;
                // perform OK button tasks
            }
        }
    }, lastSelectedHour, lastSelectedMinute, true);

    timePickerDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            // perform CANCEL button tasks
        }
    });

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        timePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                    isTimeSelected = true;
                }
            }
        });

        timePickerDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
                    isTimeSelected = false;
                }
            }
        });

        timePickerDialog.setCancelable(false);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Time");
    }
    timePickerDialog.show();
}
```