# TimePickerDialog Cancel Button not dropping data

Tags: android, timepicker

I know this has been asked many times, but I can't find an answer to suit my problem.

So I have an activity which has a button where its' text is the current time (the time the activity was accessed). I can click on the button to show a TimePickerDialog where I can change the time, click the 'Set' button and the button updates with the new time. So far, so good, so basic.

My problem is that if I launch the TimePicker, change the time, click the Cancel button and then launch the TimePicker again, the displayed time is the time I cancelled instead of the original time from the button that launched it. If I cancel the TimePicker, I want it to forget any previous data.

Here is my code:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        recordTime = new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, true);
        recordTime.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                recordTime.dismiss();
            }
        });

        recordTime.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface arg0) {
                recordTime.cancel();
                recordTime.dismiss();
            }

        });
        return recordTime;

    }
    return null;
}


// the callback received when the user sets the time in the dialog
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                mHour = hourOfDay;
                mMinute = minute;
                updateTimeDisplay();
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I cancel the TimePicker, I want it to forget any previous data.

Each time a Dialog is opened with `showDialog()` it passes through `onPrepareDialog()`, simply reset the time here. If the user clicked `Set` the new time is saved in `mHour` and `mMinute`, if the dialog is cancelled for any reason this restores the original data:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        recordTime.updateTime(mHour, mMinute);
    }
}
```

You can easily call this in the OnCancelListener as well:

```
recordTime.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        recordTime.updateTime(mHour, mMinute);
    }
});
```

Also your original OnCancel and OnDismiss listeners seem redundant. What are you trying to do with them?

You should know that `onDismiss()` is called if the user clicks `Set`, `Cancel`, or uses the back button. If the user clicks `Set` you don't want to call the `onCancel()` method is `onDismiss()`. Don't treat `onCancel()` and `onDismiss()` as the same methods.

Comment: Thanks. I found that just using onPrepareDialog did the trick. Using .setOnCancelListener by itself, didn't restore the original time.

Comment: Can check running code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724781/timepickerdialog-cancel-button/47043247#47043247 as well

Answer (score 0):

You are never reseting your date. If you reset your date/time in the `onCancel` method, everything should work fine.

Comment: How would I do that? As a quick test I put in final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
           mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
           mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE); but that didn't help.

Comment: I've changed my code example to incorporate your suggestion; but it still doesn't work