# How can I add new button in date picker widget in android?

Tags: android, time, widget, picker, timepicker

I want to add new button,which is clear button, to date picker widget and time picker widget in my android application. In default, these widgets have two button,set and cancel. How can I add one more button to these two button

Is it possible? If yes, can you give some example?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I implemented the "Clear" button in my app. When the user clicks Clear, the year/month/day values are all 0. You can use onDateSet() in your app for both the Set button and Clear button this way.

I referenced the Android source code (\frameworks\base\core\java\android\app\DatePickerDialog.java).

I also used the help of [esilver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981308/1198943).

```
public class DatePickerDialogPlus extends DatePickerDialog {
    private final DatePicker mDatePicker;
    private final OnDateSetListener mCallBack;

    /**
     * @param context The context the dialog is to run in.
     * @param callBack How the parent is notified that the date is set.
     * @param year The initial year of the dialog.
     * @param monthOfYear The initial month of the dialog.
     * @param dayOfMonth The initial day of the dialog.
     */
    public DatePickerDialogPlus(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack, 
            int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, 0, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        mCallBack = callBack;

        Context themeContext = getContext();
        setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, 
            themeContext.getText(R.string.datePicker_setButton), this);
        setButton(BUTTON_NEUTRAL, 
            themeContext.getText(R.string.datePicker_clearButton), this);
        setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, 
            themeContext.getText(R.string.datePicker_cancelButton), null);
        setIcon(0);
        setTitle(R.string.datePicker_title);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
            themeContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.date_picker_dialog, null);
        setView(view);
        mDatePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        mDatePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if (mCallBack != null) {
            if (which == BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
                mDatePicker.clearFocus();
                mCallBack.onDateSet(mDatePicker, mDatePicker.getYear(), 
                    mDatePicker.getMonth(), mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth());
            } else if (which == BUTTON_NEUTRAL) {
                mDatePicker.clearFocus();
                mCallBack.onDateSet(mDatePicker, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this code, but in ICS clear and set button don't work correct always

Answer (score 43):

Just add a neutral button.

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, 0, callback, year, month, day);
dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "Name", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        //Your code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Simply create this class!

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;

public class DatePickerWithNeutral extends DatePickerDialog {

    public DatePickerWithNeutral(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack,
                            int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, 0, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, ("Ok"), this);
        setButton(BUTTON_NEUTRAL, ("Something"), this); // ADD THIS
        setButton(BUTTON_NEGATIVE, ("Cancel"), this);
    }
}
```

Then use this to add functionality to it!

```
date.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL).setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Neutral Button Clicked!", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

---

Looks like this

[image]

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

The question also referenced adding a *clear* button to a TimePicker, which is what brought me here.

For anyone interested, here's how to do it for a TimePicker within a Dialog Fragment.

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener, TimePickerDialog.OnClickListener {

    private static final String HOURS_ARG_KEY = "hours";
    private static final String MINUTES_ARG_KEY = "minutes";
    private static final String TARGET_ARG_KEY = "target";

    public static TimePickerFragment newInstance(int hours, int minutes, int targetResId,...other values...) {
        TimePickerFragment tpf = new TimePickerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        //Setup the TimePickerFragment with some args if required.

        args.putInt(HOURS_ARG_KEY, hours);
        args.putInt(MINUTES_ARG_KEY, minutes);
        args.putInt(TARGET_ARG_KEY, targetResId);
        tpf.setArguments(args);

        return tpf;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker if we get nothing from
        // from the arguments.
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        int hour = getArguments().getInt(HOURS_ARG_KEY,c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        int minute = getArguments().getInt(MINUTES_ARG_KEY, c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, false);

        // And add the third button to clear the target field.
        tpd.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,getActivity().getText(R.string.clear), this);

        return tpd;
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // Do something with the time chosen by the user

        int target = getArguments().getInt(TARGET_ARG_KEY,0);

        //Get reference of host activity (XML Layout File) TextView widget
        TextView txt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(target);
        //Format the hourOfDay and minute values, then display the user changed time on the TextView
        txt.setText(...FORMATTED TIME...);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        if(which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL) {
            int target = getArguments().getInt(TARGET_ARG_KEY,0);

            //Get reference of host activity (XML Layout File) TextView widget
            TextView txt = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(target);
            //Clear the field.
            txt.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

Then, load it up from your Activity:

```
TimePickerFragment tpf = TimePickerFragment.newInstance(...args...);
tpf.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

Comment: You save my day dude!!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to add a new button named CLEAR which will clear selected date then,

```
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
            val datePicker = DatePickerDialog(this, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { _, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
                val date = (dayOfMonth.toString() + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1).toString() + "-" + year.toString())
                et_date.setText(date)
            }, yy, mm, dd)
            datePicker.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "CLEAR") { dialog, which ->
                if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL) {
                    et_date.setText("")
                }
            }
            datePicker.show()
```

P.S. above code is in kotlin language.