# Cancel button on datepicker android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-datepicker

I have a FromDate `EditText` to which I have added an image. Now when I click the image a `Datepicker` is shown. Now when I choose some date and click on **Set** `Button`, the date is set in the `EditText`. Problem is that, when I click Cancel `Button`, the date picker is gone and the prev activity does not gain focus until I press Back! No touch event works on the screen.
Please help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe this could be the best way to do it...but some how the following code works; got some guidance from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4981308/840520

```
    dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {                 
                  dialog.dismiss();
                  onBackPressed();
               }
            }
          });
```

Since I have a project delivery, this works for me now.However, I'm still looking for a decent way of handling this. Does android platform doesn't handle the cancel button as it does for other dialogs?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented date picker with cancel event handling and with work with EditText.. May be it help someone who wants to clear text on cancel event..

```
private EditText dob;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.browse);


        dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDob);
                /* For DOB EditText */
        dob.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (v == dob)
                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                return false;
            }
        });
}


    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        final int cyear, cmonth, cday;

        if (dob.getText().equals("")) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            cyear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            cmonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            cday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        } else {
            String[] datestr = dob.getText().toString().split("-");
            cyear = Integer.parseInt(datestr[0]);
            cmonth = Integer.parseInt(datestr[1]);
            cday = Integer.parseInt(datestr[2]);
        }
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            // return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, cyear,
            // cmonth,cday);
            DatePickerDialog dateDlg = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            String date_selected = String.valueOf(year)
                                    + "-"
                                    + ((String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                                            .length() == 1 ? "0"
                                            + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                                            : String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)))
                                    + "-"
                                    + ((String.valueOf(dayOfMonth).length() == 1 ? "0"
                                            + String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)
                                            : String.valueOf(dayOfMonth)));
                            dob.setText(date_selected);

                        }

                    }, cyear, cmonth, cday);
            dateDlg.setTitle(getString(R.string.dob));
            dateDlg.setCancelable(false);
            dateDlg.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         dob.setText("");
                         dialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });

            return dateDlg;

        }
        return null;
    }
```