# How to finish activity when date picker dialog on cancel button is clicked

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have implemented the date picker dialog on my activity and it works fine. When i click cancel the ate picker is dismissed so the buttons work. However i would like to capture the cancel button event and add more code to it to finish the activity but i cannot seem to be able to handle that. 
This is my code:

```js
public class DatePickerActivity extends Activity {
    static final int DATE_PICKER_ID = 1111;
    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_picker);
        // Get current date by calender

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        year  = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        day   = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID);
    }
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_ID:

                // open datepicker dialog.
                // set date picker for current date
                // add pickerListener listner to date picker
                return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

            year  = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day   = selectedDay;

            // Show selected date
            Log.d("Date selected", String.valueOf(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                    .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" ")));

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("year", String.valueOf(new StringBuilder().append(year )));
            intent.putExtra("month", String.valueOf(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)));
            intent.putExtra("day",  String.valueOf(new StringBuilder().append(day)));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();

        }
    };
}
```

What i have tried is to add this onclick method like:

```js
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(which==Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
        {
            Log.i("dialog click", "dialog negative button clicked");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

But this is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928902/how-do-i-detect-a-cancel-click-of-the-datepicker-dialog

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DanielNugent . I meant using my code above, your suggestion requires a different approach to the whole code.

Comment: Doesn't look like it would be that much of a change, you would basically add the code from the accepted answer into your `onCreateDialog()` code.  Instead of `return new DatePickerDialog()` you would need a DatePickerDialog reference, e.g. `DatePickerDialog ref = new DatePickerDialog()`, call `setButton()` on the reference, and then return it.

Comment: That worked great!!I implemented your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

```
 @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
      case DATE_PICKER_ID:

        // open datepicker dialog.
        // set date picker for current date
        // add pickerListener listner to date picker
        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);


        dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Text", new DialogInterface
            .OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
              // Do Stuff
             Log.i("dialog click", "dialog negative button clicked");
            dialog.dismiss();
            }
          }
        });
        return dialog;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: @SteveKamau: Glad..:)

Answer (score 4):

Make a class for DatePickerDialog and call it from `onCreate()` as follows:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,this,year,month,day);

        // Return the DatePickerDialog
        return  dpd;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        // Your code here
    }

    // Set a Listener for Dialog Cancel button click event
    /*
        onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            This method will be invoked when the dialog is canceled.
     */
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog){
        // Send a message to confirm cancel button click
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Date Picker Canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Call it from `onCreate()`

```
 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_date_picker);
        DialogFragment dFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        // Show the date picker dialog fragment
        dFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
   }
```

Comment: is this supported from API 10 and below?

Comment: Haven't checked on API 10 but i guess yes it supports.

Comment: Looks like a clean approach, i like it. Thanks for your solution!