# autoclose DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

I am using the following code to create a `DatePickerDialog` from an `EditText`.

```
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

EditText datePicker = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.popUpDate);
datePicker.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

datePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new DatePickerDialog(AddAccount.this, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                datePicker.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
            }
        }, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
    }
});
}
```

Is it possible to have the default one automatically close after a date is chosen? Or would that require a complete remake of the `datepicker` widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **MyPicker**  class :)

```
    import static yourPackageName.MainActivity.sdf; // get static imports


    public class MyPicker extends DatePickerDialog {

    Context context;
    @Override
    public DatePicker getDatePicker() {
        return super.getDatePicker();
    }


    public MyPicker(Context context, int themeResId, OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, themeResId, listener, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        datePicker.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
        datePickerDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

now assuming your main class in **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();


    public static String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
    public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    public static EditText datePicker;
    public static MyPicker datePickerDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datePicker = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.popUpDate);
        datePicker.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

        datePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                datePickerDialog = new MyPicker(MainActivity.this, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    }
                }, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }

        });
    }

}
}
```

---

or if you don't need to apply styles

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public  String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
    public  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    public  EditText datePicker;
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datePicker = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.popUpDate);
        datePicker.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));

        datePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, null, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                        datePicker.setText(sdf.format(calendar.getTime()));
                        datePickerDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                datePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: I think it similar to my answer. and with your `MyPicker`, the Context you have define is not use, also the fucntion getDatePicker is not necessary

Comment: yes that's a class i used which extends DatePickerDialog. Removed as i can an posted it.In any way we are accessing the same method onDateChanged method which allows to identify date changes and with my first one i applied a theme

Comment: @Charuka is it possible to set "today's" date through the `datePickerDialog` as the current date when the activity is called? It seems to always default to the last chosen one.

Comment: Simply call  `myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();` again when you go away from your datePickerActivity  eg : 

`public void load(){
    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondAct.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}`

Answer (score 2):

[DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html) containing an [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html). And [DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html) have [OnDateChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html).
You can use [OnDateChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener.html) to listener when you choose a date like

```
final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
    new DatePickerDialog(YourActivity.this, null, year, month, day);

datePickerDialog.getDatePicker()
    .init(year, month, day, new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "day" + dayOfMonth + "-month" + monthOfYear + 1 + "-year" + year, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // dismiss the popup when choose a date 
            datePickerDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
datePickerDialog.show();
```

This solution will work for your case but I think it is not very good about User experience (UX) because almost Android app use default DatePickerDialog flow

Answer (score 1):

> The Current behavior is fine?
>
> If it will automatically close ...! then how system will know you pick
>   the desired date and time or you accidentally pick it..... there no
>   sense of close it automatically instead of event fire.

But you can close it on `onDateSet`.

**Update**:   You can close it like this.

```
// open datepicker dialog.
// set date picker for current date
// add pickerListener listner to date picker

   DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener, year, month,day);
   dialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Text", new DialogInterface
            .OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
              // Do Stuff
             Log.i("dialog click", "dialog negative button clicked");
            dialog.dismiss();
            }
          }
        });
   dialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: It will close if you choose a date, if you accidentally chose one it won't be hard to reopen. The idea is you are more likely to choose a correct date than accidentally clicking one. So automatically closing it would be a better route for the overall user. -- The issue is I am not sure what the command to include within the `oneDateSet`

Comment: are you using android builtin date picker or any other lib?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104181/how-to-finish-activity-when-date-picker-dialog-on-cancel-button-is-clicked) solution is when the cancel button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

@Phan, Try with the below code

```
DatePickerDialog dialog;

datePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddAccount.this, R.style.AppTheme_Dialog, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                datePicker.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

if(dialog != null) {
dialog.dismiss();
}
            }
        }, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
dialog.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: the OP want to dismiss dialog immediately when we choose a date, not when we choose a day then press done (or press ok)